# Почему шейдер Opengl ES 3.0 на Android 8 не собирается

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl, opengles

Написал шейдер для андроид версии Opengl ES 3.0

Он прекрасно собирается по андроид 10-11, по при запуске программы на андроид 8
получаю ошибку что максимальная версия шейдера 101
в документации написано что должна быть поддержка с 4.3+

Как собрать этот шейдер на андроид 6,7,8?

```
#version 300 es
in vec3 a_xyz;
in vec2 a_uv0;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
out vec2 v_uv0;
void main()
{        
    vec4 p = u_matrix * vec4(a_xyz, 1.0);
    v_uv0 = a_uv0;
    gl_Position = p;
}
```

Comment: устройство скорее всего не поддерживает 3 версию, и это не зависит от версии Андроида, используйте  uses-feature чтобы отсечь такие устройства

Comment: про vulkan видимо тоже стоит забыть?

Comment: Странно ожидать поддержки vulkan на андроид 8, когда тот вышел на следующий год после представления первой публичной версии vulkan.